# SAS how do I use variable number as seed in proc surveyselect?

Tags: sas

So I have a dataset that has the sample size and the seed for each stratum.

How do I reference these in a proc surveyselect?

My Code:

```
proc surveyselect data=hca2 (where =(disp=1 and fin=1 and dol_str=1)) 
out=Disp1_Fin1_DS1
method=SRS
seed=seed
sampsize=samp_n;
run;
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I think you'll have to pull the seed out separately, I'm not aware of a method to provide that via a data set.

Answer (score 2):

There is a secondary input data set reference in `proc surveyselect`, which may be your anwser.

[SAS Help Center: Secondary Input Data Set](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetVersion=15.1&docsetTarget=statug_surveyselect_details25.htm&locale=en)

And the following is a simple example:

```
proc sort data = sashelp.class out = class;
  by sex name;
run;

data config;
  do sex = 'F','M';
    _seed_ = 42;
    _nsize_ = 6;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc surveyselect data = class out = result method = srs seed=config sampsize=config outseed;
  strata sex;
run;
```

Open data set `result` and see if it is what you need.

Comment: Nice! There's always a danger in saying something can't be done but happy there's a much easier solution!